# Can multiple service perform work parallelly at the same time

Tags: java, android, service, android-intentservice

I am developing an app which has multiple features which need to perform work in the background.

Each feature needs to run at the same time and perform some work parallelly.

Currently, I am using JobIntentService to perform work but I have noticed that when I try to run multiple JobIntentServices then only one run while others are made to wait and executed one by one.

I am planning to use the Service. I want to know can 5 services run at the same time and perform work parallelly?

If no then is there any alternative?

Any help would be grateful.

Comment: Yes. It is possible to run services parallelly in Android.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please post an answer for me to accept it :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes. It is possible to run services parallelly in Android.**

Answer (score 1):

Yes they should be able to run parallel (as pointed out by @Omkar), depending on the work load that the device is already having. The reason your JobIntentServices weren’t running parallel is because the OS will choose when to call those services when it thinks is best, thus sometimes they won’t run “right away”, using a Service would be the best solution for parallel running work that needs to be ran ASAP

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But sorry I had to accept his answer as he said the answer first. But anyway you explaination a treat for me. Thanks :)

Comment: No worries! Just wanted to give a bit of an explanation :)